# Calculating triple integral over a region G

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

So i have a triple integral:

$$\iiint\limits_G (x^2+2y^2){dV}$$

where region G is defined as:

$$(x^2+2y^2+4z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}=x^2+2y^2$$

So my first idea is to use spherical coordinates since the left part is simmilar to a sphere, but seem a little different.

So i have: $$x=rcos{({\phi})}cos{{(\theta})}$$
$$y=rsin(\phi)cos(\theta)$$
$$z=rsin(\theta)$$

So how can i get bounds of my coordinates?

Normally $phi$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ but am not sure how can i check it, i have to visualize the region i guess, but am having problems with this one.

Any help regarding boundaries, calcualting the integral, or correcting my initial ideas is welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=2r\cos\phi\sin\theta, y=\sqrt{2}r\sin\phi\sin\theta, z=r\cos\theta$. Then from the equation we get: $2r = \sin^2 \theta$.

So our boundaries are $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}; 0 \le \phi  \le 2\pi; 0 \le r \le \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{2}$. Now the integral becomes:

$$\iiint\limits_G (x^2+2y^2){dV} = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{2}} 8r^3 r^2 \sin \theta \  drd\theta d\phi$$

This should be computable.

Comment: why is $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @MathIsTheWayOfLife There's no restirction on the value of $\theta$ and from spherical coordinates we know that $\theta$ is in that range.